# Eclipse - Merge tool override previous commits

Tags: git, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I'm using Eclipse 2019-12 working with Git using Eclipse UI only

If I commit to master before pull previous commits I can't push my commit to server

I used Team -> Merge Tool (Merge option was disabled)

I merge the changes (shows some files) and then push to upstream

Expected: all commits are merged

Actual: previous commits weren't added to master

Is using Merge tool wrong for conflict? can I use rebase without losing any commits?

- can't pull previous commits after commit

Comment: Just hit the _Refresh_ button in the _Git Staging_ or _Git Repositories_ view after doing something Git related outside of Eclipse. By the way, make sure not to use outdated software (the current JGit/EGit version is 5.8.1; the version included in the Eclipse 2019-12 was 5.6).

Comment: @howlger I work with eclipse only, (didn't understand the *outside of Eclipse* comment), so it's a bug of old version?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _Merge Tool_?

Comment: @howlger Team-> Merge Tool

Comment: Most of what you do here depends on what you have in the Git config. Maybe you have to rebase it instead of merge your commits. It is unclear to me what you are doing.

Comment: @howlger I think you are in right direction, how should I set git config to support Merge Tool?

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Rebasing

Comment: @howlger so the issue I must do rebase before Merge Tool?